# Disable sd card slot on Android device

Tags: android

is possible to disable/block SD card slot on android devices?

If someone put some SD card in their phone it will be blocked so it will not be possible to copy or install anything from mobile to that card?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: A big screw driver or some glue will do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.